# Can I protect a subfolder of public when serving Laravel project via Apache?

Tags: laravel, apache, basic-authentication

I've a running webapp made in Laravel and served through Apache.

As well known, Laravel's app root is `<path_to_project_code>/public`.

I want a protected folder *under* `/public`, for precision: `<path>/public/apidoc`.

I am trying this

```
<VirtualHost <ip_redacted>:80>
        ServerName  www.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
        ServerAdmin info@mycompany.it
        ServerPath  /www.mydomain.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mydomain.com/public/
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

        <Directory /var/www/www.mydomain.com/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory "/var/www/www.mydomain.com/public/apidoc">
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Authentication Required"
            AuthUserFile "/etc/htpasswd/.www.mydomain.com.passwd"
            Require valid-user

            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhosts/www-mydomain-com/access.log vhost_combined
        ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhosts/www-mydomain-com/error.log

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

So configured, `www.domain.com` is served from `....../public`, and it's ok.
And `www.domain.com/apidoc` is served from `....../public/apidoc`, and it's ok.

But **accessing www.mydomain.com/apidoc DO NOT requires http auth** as I want and as I expected.

### Added Info

The content of /public/apidoc are static html files generated by APIDocjs.

The simple equivalent of Nginx, working in development, of what I am trying to do is

```
location /apidoc {
   auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
   auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/sites-auth/www.mydomain.com.password;
}
```

**I simply need to port these 4 rows from Nginx to Apache**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

I removed the entire section

```
<Directory "/var/www/www.mydomain.com/public/apidoc">
...
</Directory>
```

Than created `/public/apidoc/.htaccess` with this content

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "APIDoc"
AuthUserFile  /etc/htpasswd/.www.mydomain.com.passwd
Require valid-user
```

Require valid-user